# Como visualizar arquivos .zip usando java para android

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber como faço um programa que consegue visualizar arquivos .zip no android usando java, estou procurando ha um tempo e não achei ;(...Se possível da maneira mais fácil,se é que existe uma...

Obrigado!

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que seria **visualizar arquivos .zip**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fala DrKill,

Realmente fica meio difícil de entender qual sua dúvida, como assim visualizar?

Você pode dezipar um arquivo, exemplo:

```
private boolean unpackZip(String path, String zipname){       
     InputStream is;
     ZipInputStream zis;
     try 
     {
         String filename;
         is = new FileInputStream(path + zipname);
         zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));          
         ZipEntry ze;
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int count;

         while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) 
         {
             // zapis do souboru
             filename = ze.getName();

             // Need to create directories if not exists, or
             // it will generate an Exception...
             if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                File fmd = new File(path + filename);
                fmd.mkdirs();
                continue;
             }

             FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

             // cteni zipu a zapis
             while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
             {
                 fout.write(buffer, 0, count);             
             }

             fout.close();               
             zis.closeEntry();
         }

         zis.close();
     } 
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     }

    return true;
}
```

Mas procure reformular sua pergunta, ai fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Abraços.

Comment: obrigado!Era Isso q eu procurava